# Heroku postgres: Connection timed out... TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, vpn

I'm making a new telegram bot and wanna deploy it to Heroku. I made a postgres database with that (heroku). I used to use NordVPN, now I'm not, and I noticed that I can't connect to my database anymore, while using other VPNs. When I run my bot (with other VPNs), I face this error:

```
Exception: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on host "ec2-18-211-41-246.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (18.211.41.246) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

It works fine without VPN though. As I searched, It's because of the firewall. But I made windows firewall off, and also paused my anti-virus, and still got the error. Any suggestions on how to make it work with any VPN?

Some information:

```
>>> systeminfo
...
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:                10.0.19042 N/A Build 19042
...

>>> python --version
Python 3.8.0

>>> pip freeze | findstr psycopg2
psycopg2==2.8.6

>>> netstat -a -n | findstr "5432"
TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::]:5432              [::]:0                 LISTENING

>>> telnet 0.0.0.0 5432
Connecting To 0.0.0.0...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5432: Connect failed

>>> heroku version
heroku/7.54.1 win32-x64 node-v12.21.0

>>> heroku pg:info -a my-bot
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-dev
Status:                Available
Connections:           0/20
PG Version:            13.3
Created:               2021-08-08 07:47 UTC
Data Size:             8.1 MB/1.00 GB (In compliance)
Tables:                1
Rows:                  15/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
```

The above commands are done bellow a VPN connection
Note: Telegram is blocked in my country, so in order to be able to code telegram bots, I have to use a VPN

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by installing OpenVPN and using freeopenvpn configs. I don't know how did that help, but I'm leaving this here for anyone who found this problem in the future